# TreeView with Caliburn Micro c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, caliburn.micro

I am trying to get a treeview working with my data. I am using WPF MVVM with Caliburn Micro, but somehow i can't get the bindings to work as i want.

My data in the simplified form looks like this.

A Class Operation

```
public class Operation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Parameters> parameters { get; set; }

    public Operation()
    {
        parameters = new ObservableCollection<Parameters>();
    }
}
```

and Class Parameters

```
    public class Parameters
{
    public string par { get; set; }
    public double val { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Joints> Joints { get; set; }

    public Parameters()
    {
        Joints = new ObservableCollection<Joints>();
    }
}
```

And Joints class

In my ShellViewModel i initialize these classes and put some data inside...

```
public Operation _Operation = new Operation();
int moveId = 0;

public BindableCollection<Operation> Operations
    {
        get { return _Operations; }
        set 
        { 
            _Operations = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Operations);
        }
    }

 public ShellViewModel()
    {

    var moveOperation = new Operation
        {
            Id = moveId,
            Name = $"Move{moveId}"
        };
        Joints jt1 = new Joints() { Par = "J0", Val = 2.34 };
        Joints jt2 = new Joints() { Par = "J0", Val = 0.34 };
        Parameters parm = new Parameters { par = "a", val = 2.13 };
        parm.Joints.Add(jt1);
        parm.Joints.Add(jt2);
        moveOperation.Parameters.Add(parm);
```

}

My goal is to have it visualised in treeview something like this

```
 - Move1
    -a 2.13
    -Joints
      -J0 2.34
      -J1 0.34
 - Move2
    -a 'some value'
    -Joints
      -J0 'some value'
      -J1 'some value'
```

But however i tried making xaml to work, i have never been able to show the children... This is just one of the examples that i did.

```
                    <TreeView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="150"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Operations}">
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding par}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text=" " ></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding val}"/>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Par}"/>

                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Val}"/>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Par}"/>

                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>
```

Please any guidance or help would be appritiated, i have lost three full days only trying to get this treeview working. Thank you!

EDIT:
I had a typo in the Parameters class thanks for pointing it out.
I wanted to move Joints one level lower than before, that was actually the problem i was having, how to get onto the deeper levels

Comment: The parameters property is lowercase while it is capitalized in your binding.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! Helped a bit!

Answer (score 0):

In your XAML for tree view you have to do like this to get children.

Add your Operation class and Parameter namespace in XAML like below.

`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TxsDiagnosticTool"`

```
 <TreeView Name="trvFamilies" ItemsSource="{Binding Operations}" MinHeight="150" >
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Parent}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Parameters}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding par0 }" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding val0 }" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>  
        </TreeView>
```

In Your Code

Operation Class:

```
public class Operation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Parameters> Parameters { get; set; }

    public Operation()
    {
        Parameters = new ObservableCollection<Parameters>();
    }
}
```

Parameters class:

```
public class Parameters
{
    public string par0 { get; set; }
    public string par1 { get; set; }
    public double val0 { get; set; }
    public double val1 { get; set; }
}
```

In ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<Operation> operations= new ObservableCollection<Operation>();
public ObservableCollection<Operation> Operations
  {
     get { return operations; }
     set
     {
        //Replace with your property changed code.
        //SetProperty(ref operations, value); 
     }
   }
int moveId = 0;


public ShellViewModel()
    {

        Operation operation1 = new Operation() { Id = moveId, Name = "Move1" };
        operation1.parameters.
        Add(new Parameters() { par0 = "J0", val0 = 2.34, par1 = "J1", val1 = 0.43 });

        moveId++;

        Operation operation2 = new Operation() { Id = moveId, Name = "Move2" };
        operation2.parameters.
        Add(new Parameters() { par0 = "J0", val0 = 5.32, par1 = "J1", val1 = 3.33 });

        Operations.Add(operation1);
        Operations.Add(operation2);
         moveId++;
    }
```

Comment: I have edited a question a bit, where my data contains one more level of children. How do i access that, in my case its Joints.

Comment: Also i have tried adding the DataType tags in xaml, but they just return errors ( The name Parent does not exist in  that namespace and Parameters is not supported in WPF)